# Extract from String with regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to extract special parts of an String, that are marked.

```
String input = "$nick=someone$$message=something$";
```

Now I want to split this String into 2 Smaller Strings.

```
String nick = "someone";
String message = "something";
```

I know, that i can somehow do that using regular Expressions and the `String.replaceFirst()` method. But i dont really understand how that works.

Comment: Are you trying to assign the value `someone` to the string variable `nick` based on this input string? Do you know the name of the variables - or do you expect to create variables based on this? That would be hard (impossible) to do in Java. Maybe you can clarify your question?

Comment: [The 30 Minute Regex Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial)

Comment: Get help here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html

Comment: You can't assign to two `String` instances with these names. You had better use a `Map<String, String>` here.

Comment: The input String will always be in that format.. $nick=$$message=$ so i will always be creating 2 substrings from that. I just need a way to extract those 2 Substrings.

Comment: Then you don't even need a regex for that, simple string indexing etc will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Java [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class to match your input explicitly with the regex (in string format): `"\\$nick=(.+?)\\$\\$message=(.+?)\\$"`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "$nick=someone$$message=something$";
    String nick = null;
    String message = null;

    java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\$nick=(.+?)\\$\\$message=(.+?)\\$");
    java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if (m.find()) {
        nick = m.group(1);
        message = m.group(2);
    }

    System.out.println("Nick: "+nick);
    System.out.println("Message: "+message);
}
```

Output:

```
Nick: someone
Message: something
```

#### Edit:

I see from your comments the string has a fixed format. In that case, [`String#indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) with [`String#substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) can be used for a simpler approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "$nick=someone$$message=something$";
    String nick = input.substring(input.indexOf("$nick=")+"$nick=".length(), input.indexOf("$$message="));
    String message = input.substring(input.indexOf("$$message=")+"$$message=".length(),input.length()-1);

    System.out.println("Nick: "+nick);
    System.out.println("Message: "+message);
}
```

Comment: It's `java.util.regex.Pattern` and `java.util.regex.Matcher`. I edited the answer. Try it out again.

Answer (score 1):

This will find all `String`s delimited by "=" before and "$" after in your input `String`:

```
String input = "$nick=someone$$message=something$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("=(.+?)\\$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
someone
something
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this code to see how you can extract the data out of your input string:

```
    String input = "$nick=someone$$message=something$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$([^=]+)=([^\\$]+)\\$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String key = matcher.group(1);
        String value = matcher.group(2);
        System.out.println(key + " = " + value);
    }
```